# With Golang Templates how can I set a variable in each template?

Tags: templates, go

How can I set a variable in each template that I can use in other templates e.g.

`{{ set title "Title" }}`

in one template then in my layout

`<title> {{ title }} </title>`

Then when it's rendered

`tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("layout.html", "home.html")`

it will set the title according to whatever was set in `home.html` instead of having to make a `struct` for each view page when it isn't really necessary. I hope I made sense, thanks.

Just for clarification:

```
layout.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }} </title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>

home.html:
{{ set Title "Home" . }}
<h1> {{ Title }} Page </h1>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use the Value in another template you can pipeline it to the dot:

```
{{with $title := "SomeTitle"}}
{{$title}} <--prints the value on the page
{{template "body" .}}
{{end}}
```

body template:

```
{{define "body"}}
<h1>{{.}}</h1> <--prints "SomeTitle" again
{{end}}
```

As far as i know it is not possible to go upwards in the chain.
So `layout.html` gets rendered before `home.html`, so you cant pass a value back.

In your example it would be the best solution to use a struct and pass it from the `layout.html` to the `home.html` using the `dot`:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type WebData struct {
    Title string
}

func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("layout.html", "home.html")
    wd := WebData{
        Title: "Home",
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, &wd)
}

func pageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("layout.html", "page.html")
    wd := WebData{
        Title: "Page",
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, &wd)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/home", homeHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/page", pageHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{.Title}} </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{template "body" .}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
{{define "body"}}
<h1>home.html {{.Title}}</h1>
{{end}}
```

**page.html**

```
{{define "body"}}
<h1>page.html {{.Title}}</h1>
{{end}}
```

Also go has a nice documentation on how to use templates:

http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/